# How to disable "compiler does not halt on function prototype mismatch" error in configure?

Tags: c++, curl, makefile, clang, configure

I am trying to compile curl source on my mac and before running makefile I did run the configure:

```
./configure --disable-shared --enable-static --disable-dependency-tracking --host=armv7-apple-darwin --disable-ldap
```

And it gave the:

```
configure: error: compiler does not halt on function prototype mismatch.
```

How do I disable it?  My compiler environmental variable is: `CC=/usr/bin/clang++`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply this [patch](https://svn.cactuscode.org/projects/ExternalLibraries/curl/branches/Cactus_4.3.0/dist/configure.patch) and retry the build. Perhaps, you'd wish to exclude the part regarding `configure.ac` or run `autoconf` manually.

Comment: It does help with the error, but creates other ones. Apparently, as I understand only llvm-gcc can be used for Iphone, not clang